# How can I display empirical pdf of my 100x1 vector data in Matlab?

Tags: distributions, multiple-comparisons, matlab, density-function, data-visualization

I have a data which is 100x1 vector. How can I display its empirical pdf in Matlab? Also, if I want to compare the pdf of three vectors on the same graph, then how to do that?

Right now I am using [pdfplot.m](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/8578-pdfplot) file to plot my empirical pdf, however when I want to compare the 3 distributions by using 'hold on', then firstly its not working and secondly all the distributions are in same color. Thanks!

Also, I don't want to plot cdf or histogram.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is that `histc` plots bars instead of, say lines; the bars are plotted over one another. you should edit `pdfplot` to plot lines instead. look for the `hist` command and alter it.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using the [ksdensity](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/stats/ksdensity.html) function. In the following example I compare the pdf of the data in column 1 of matrix 1 with the pdf of the data in column 2 of matrix 2:

```
[f,x] = ksdensity(mat1(:,1));
plot(x,f,'--b');hold
[f,x] = ksdensity(mat2(:,2));
plot(x,f,'--m')
legend('Data 1 pdf', 'Data 2 pdf');
```